# Only one of the 2 fields required, not working

Tags: php, html, forms

So I have a basic form, you can either enter your email, or phone number, followed by a required username. So What I want to do is an option to enter only a phone number **or** email. So this is what I'm doing

Here are my variables

```
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$phone = htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

How I check for the fields

```
if(empty($email) || empty($phone)){
    $errors['num_em'] = "Enter a valid email or phone number";
}
```

And the markup

```
    <p class="alternative">OR</p>
    <div id="DIV_7">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" id="INPUT_8" autocomplete="off"/>
    </div>
```

The issue with this is it makes me enter both email and phone, which is weird since I'm using the `OR` operator. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way it is right now, it will fail if one or another is empty.

What you want is the `AND` operator `&&`.

```
if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && empty($phone))
{
    $errors['num_em'] = "Enter a valid email or phone number";
}
```

[**Live DEMO**](https://eval.in/173171)

Why?

Because if email is empty and phone is empty we fail.

But if email is not empty and phone is the requirement does not met so we are safe as in having 1 filled and the other empty or not.

Comment: Well now here's the issue, if the user did enter an email, I'd used `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`, in an if statement, would I put this in the if statement you supplied? Or would this be another issue?

Comment: Its still asking me to enter a valid email, even though I'm not entering an email....

Comment: Well the phone is not empty. So I'd expect it not to ask. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ($email == "" && $phone == "") {
    $errors['num_em'] = "Enter either a valid email or phone number";
} else if ((strlen($email) > 0) && (strlen($phone) > 0)) {
    $errors['num_em'] = "Enter either a valid email or phone number";
}
```

This way if both fields are empty, it gives an error. If both fields are filled, you still get an error. So only 1 of the field can be entered.